# Drop down list selected index event in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Drop down list selected index event in asp.net mvc 4.0 with postback ....

I want to retiain the selected value in dropdown list ...

my requirement is i had three drop down list in view...in need the selected values for threee drop downs

in any action ....

can u help the same as soon as possilble...

> Key point is that we should not use
>   any javascript to get this
>
> Another point i want all this in the
>   controller itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we generally do is, populate a property (Selected) in the controller and when iterating through the items in the view , check for that property to preserve the selected item as shown below.

```
  <select  >

        @foreach (var item in Model.DDLItems)
                    {

                        var selectMode = item.Selected ? "selected" : "";
                        <option value="value" @selectMode >item.DisplayText</option>     

                    }
</select>
```